# What do you use instead of butter (on pancakes)?

Tags: veganism, dairy-substitutes, cooking

I just recently started a vegan diet about a month ago.

I've been enjoying several vegan pancake recipes, but I'm not sure what to use instead of butter for the topping? I know some margarines are vegan but not sure if they are all that great for you.

Comment: is butter `all that great for you` in the first place?

Comment: I [answered my own question](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/a/1785/74) about this. Other answers there may be more suitable for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know some margarines are vegan but not sure if they are all that great for you.

My understanding is that the health concern with margarine is that it contains [trans fat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat#Trans_fat), which has been linked to cardiovascular disease and other serious health issues (see the link). Consumption of saturated fat (found in butter) is generally thought to be linked to cardiovascular disease as well, but trans fat definitely seems to be a whole lot worse and I think you're right to avoid it.

Given that trans fat is so bad, it's not surprising that many butterlike vegetable fat spreads are made free from trans fat. At least in the UK there are lots of nice trans-fat-free vegan spreads that are clearly labelled as such. Perhaps you'll be able to find something along those lines where you are.

I haven't found any such non-dairy spread here in Chennai but I generally use coconut oil mixed 1:1 with extra virgin olive oil as a substitute for butter (or ghee).

On pancakes though I prefer peanut butter and "banoffee sauce" which I make by blending ripe banana with jaggery (coconut sugar or brown sugar will do)...

Comment: I have been putting dahl on my pancakes and calling it thosae, (dosa).

Comment: @C.S.Cameron hahaha that sounds very healthy... what kind of batter do you use? To me proper dosa is fermented rice+urad dal batter, but also it's what folks call any pancake... semolina pancake is rava dosai, millet pancake is ragi dosai, jaggery pancake is vella dosai.....

Comment: Just regular wheat flour I think. My wife calls them crepes and puts jam and cinnamon on hers. To me the plain ones  taste just like thosae from the restaurant close by. especially with dhal.

Comment: Jam & cinnamon sounds like a good option for OP of this question :D

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what Zenna answered earlier regarding the use of peanut butter, you can grind your own nut butters in the food processor. Almond butter, cashew butter, macadamia nut butter -- all are very creamy, spreadable and ''buttery''

Answer (score 0):

You could just **not use anything** in place of butter:

- 1 cup whole wheat flour
- 1/2 cup protein powder
- 1 tsp baking powder
- 1.5 cups soy milk
- 1 snack cup/container applesauce
- **1/4 cup maple syrup**
- vegan dark chocolate chips, optional

1. Mix the powders (first three ingredients)
2. Mix the remaining ingredients
3. Over medium heat, start warming a griddle or pan (use this time to let the mixture rest)
4. Pour one pancake (since my first one is usually always bad), then pour the rest 2-4 at a time

Tips: The protein powder will probably make it seem like they're not completely cooked. With a spatula or other utensil, spread out the mixture to cook thinner pancakes. I do this mainly for peace of mind because all the ones I make seem like they're not cooked enough. (You can also cook longer on a lower heat--but no body got time for dat!)